# Only Table in rpivotTable

Tags: r, shiny, pivottable.js, rpivottable

I'm using the rpivotTable package in Shiny application and I'd like to have only the choice of 'Table' for the users (no charts)
The RenderName argument is only used to choose the default display...

```
output$pivot <- renderRpivotTable(
    rpivotTable(iris, 
                rendererName = "Table" )
    )
```

Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues here.

- you can specify renderers via the anonymos `renderers` argument in `rpivotTable()`. I have the JS code form [here](https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/issues/81#issuecomment-29286097).
- however, there is a bug when only selecting one option. In this case, `rpivotTable()` wraps the argument in a list again (see the `Map()` call in the original function code) and the forwarding to JS fails.

Therefore, I accounted for this issue and extended the function a bit. Play around with aggregators/renderers to see how it behaves differently to the original `rpivotTable()` function.

```
# define own function
my_rpivotTable <- function (data, rows = NULL, cols = NULL, aggregatorName = NULL, 
          vals = NULL, rendererName = NULL, sorter = NULL, exclusions = NULL, 
          inclusions = NULL, locale = "en", subtotals = FALSE, ..., 
          width = 800, height = 600, elementId = NULL) 
{
  if (length(intersect(class(data), c("data.frame", "data.table", 
                                      "table", "structable", "ftable"))) == 0) {
    stop("data should be a data.frame, data.table, or table", 
         call. = F)
  }
  if (length(intersect(c("table", "structable", "ftable"), 
                       class(data))) > 0) 
    data <- as.data.frame(data)
  params <- list(rows = rows, cols = cols, aggregatorName = aggregatorName, 
                 vals = vals, rendererName = rendererName, sorter = sorter, 
                 ...)
  params <- Map(function(p) {
    # added to the class check -------------------------------------------------
    if (length(p) == 1 && class(p[[1]]) != "JS_EVAL") {
      p = list(p)
    }
    return(p)
  }, params)
  par <- list(exclusions = exclusions, inclusions = inclusions)
  params <- c(params, par)
  params <- Filter(Negate(is.null), params)
  x <- list(data = data, params = params, locale = locale, 
            subtotals = subtotals)
  htmlwidgets::createWidget(name = "rpivotTable", x, width = width, 
                            height = height, elementId = elementId, package = "rpivotTable")
}
```

```
# create the pivot table
my_rpivotTable(
  expand.grid(LETTERS, 1:3),
  aggregatorName = "Count",
  aggregators = list(Sum = htmlwidgets::JS('$.pivotUtilities.aggregators["Sum"]'),
                     Count = htmlwidgets::JS('$.pivotUtilities.aggregators["Count"]')),
  rendererName = "fancyTable",
  renderers = list(fancyTable = htmlwidgets::JS('$.pivotUtilities.renderers["Table"]'))

)
```